# Setup an Variable that maintain return of a method and update itself accordingly

Tags: java

Guys

I am really new for Java, and this is my first post in stack overflow. Please forgive me if I have any format error or anything else.

This is a school project. In this project, I will simulate a tortoise and hare race.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
public class T_H_Race {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int t = 1;//initial position for Tortoise
    int h = 1;//initial position for Hare
    int end = 50;
    int ran = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 10 + 1);
    int nt = tortoise(ran, h);//update position after 1st move
    int nh = hare(ran, h);//update position after 1st move


    System.out.println("\n" + "AND THRY'RE OFF!!");
    for (int i = 1; i <= end; ++i) {
        int random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 10 + 1);
        int a = tortoise(random, nt);
        int b = hare(random, nt);
                if (a < b) {
                    System.out.println("H="+a+" "+b);
                } else if (a > b) {
                    System.out.println("T="+a+" "+b);
                } else if (a == b) {
                    System.out.println("OUTH!");
                } else if (a >= 50) {
                    System.out.println("TORTOISE WIN!!");
                } else if (b >= 50) {
                    System.out.println("HARE WIN!!");
                }
        }
    }

/*
Method for Tortoise move
pre-condition current position of Tortoise
post-condition the position of that tortoise will move to base on the type of move(Random number)
*/
public static int tortoise(int random,int t) {
        if (random <= 5) {
            t = t + 3;//Tortoise has a fast plod that it will move 3 squares to right
        } else if (6 <= random && random <= 8) {
            t = t + 1;//Tortoise has a slow plod that it will move 1 squares to right
        } else if (9 <= random && random <= 10) {
            t = t - 6;//Tortoise has a slip that it will move 6 squares to left
        }

        if (t<0){
            t=0;
        }

        return t;
}

/*
Method for Hare move
pre-condition current position of Hare
post-condition the position of that hare will move to base on the type of move(Random number)
 */
public static int hare(int random, int h) {
        if (random == 1 | random == 2) {
            h = h + 9;//Hare has a big hop that it will move 9 squares to right
        } else if (3 <= random && random <= 5) {
            h = h + 1;//Hare has a small hop that it will move 1 squares to right
        } else if (random == 6) {
            h = h - 12;//Hare has a big slip that it will move 12 squares to left
        } else if (7 <= random && random <= 8) {
            h = h - 2;//Hare has a small slip that it will move 2 squares to left
        } else if (9 <= random && random <= 10) {
            h = h;//Hare falls asleep that it will not move at all
        }

        if(h<0){
            h=0;
        }
    return h;
    }
}
```

I tried to create two variables(a,b) that each maintains the current positions for tortoise and hare, and update themselves accordingly.

The example will be if hare 2 positions, "a" will become 3 from 1. Then, if hare move 9 positions, "a"  will become 12 (because 3+9). However, currently, my code always use initial position(h=1) but not current position. I know it is because I use initial position(h) as the input for the method. But I don't know how should I change my method and let the input to be the current position.

Much Appreciated for all your helps!

Comment: Hi, Guys. Thank you so much for help. Here are what I did:1. remove nt, nh. 2. change                                                             
down vote
accept
Change:

    int a = tortoise(random, nt);
    int b = hare(random, nt);     

 to :    

    int t = tortoise(random, t);
    int h = hare(random, h);     use while loop instead of for loop. Problem solved! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to declare `a` and `b` before your for loop otherwise the saved values will get re-initialised.

In you loop it will be like

```
a += tortoise(random, nt);
```

Maybe just a comment but, consider this code

```
            if (a < b) {
                System.out.println("H="+a+" "+b);
            } else if (a > b) {
                System.out.println("T="+a+" "+b);
            } else if (a == b) {
                System.out.println("OUTH!");
            }
```

the above three cases equate to 100% of the possible scenarios, so the below `else` code will never happen

```
            else if (a >= 50) {
                System.out.println("TORTOISE WIN!!");
            } else if (b >= 50) {
                System.out.println("HARE WIN!!");
            }
```

try changing it to

```
        if (a >= 50) {
                System.out.println("TORTOISE WIN!!");
                break;
        } 
        if (b >= 50) {
                System.out.println("HARE WIN!!");
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
    int a = tortoise(random, nt);
    int b = hare(random, nt);
```

into:

```
     a = tortoise(random, a);
     b = hare(random, b);
```

Declare `a` and `b` before the loop:

```
  int a=h, b=h;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

1. Remove the 1st move. It is not serving any purpose.

   int nt = tortoise(ran, h);//update position after 1st move
   int nh = hare(ran, h);//update position after 1st move
2. The first position should be inside the loop.  But variables should be declared outside.

   ```
   int a=1; // initial position, can be 0 if you want, declare outside loop
   int b= 1;// initial position, can be 0 if you want, declare outside loop

    a = tortoise(random, a);
    b = hare(random, b);
   ```

   3. Remove the for loop. It does not tell you when to exit. You are exiting after 50 moved. A Do while loop with break condition suggested in one more answer is far better.

   if (a >= 50) {
   System.out.println("TORTOISE WIN!!");
   break;
   }